# unable to use jest to upload files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my function inside my react file, **handleFileChange**.
Below is an example:

```
it('initialise the state with empty list of state', () => {
  expect(mainApp.state().items).toEqual([]);
});

it(' upload file', async () => {
  await mainApp.instance().handleFileChange(MockFile);
  expect(mainApp.state().itemsHeader).toEqual([]);
});

it('check the leng of state', () => {
  const text = mainApp.find('.total').text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

And my result is always 0, any advice?

Comment: Can you please share how `mainApp` looks like? Thanks!

Comment: Please add `mainApp` component and the error logs.

Comment: this is an example of my main https://codesandbox.io/s/new-voice-ydpew?file=/src/Main.js